# In a java regex, how can I get a character class e.g. [a-z] to match a - minus sign?

Tags: java, regex

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-z]+$");
String string = "abc-def";
assertTrue( pattern.matcher(string).matches() ); // obviously fails
```

Is it possible to have the character class match a "-" ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Don't put the minus sign between characters.

```
"[a-z-]"
```

Comment: This was downvoted, but it also works.  I always just put the dash at the end.

Comment: I'm really not sure that this is standard regexp syntax.  I don't doubt that it works, but it's almost certainly not best practice.

Comment: I beg to differ. The resulting character class is and works exactly the same. Escaping may or may not work depending on the regex dialect you use. In this case it's Java, who knows what it will be the next time. Putting the dash at the end (or the beginging) always works.

Comment: This *is* the correct syntax in every regexp dialect known to me. The minus sign does *not* have to be escaped if it's at the beginning or the end of the character class.

Comment: Escaping works everywhere except for implementations of POSIX regular expressions.  According to the information I've dug up, it seems that this is standard syntax, but it still strikes me as ugly and accident prone.  It's just bad language design that regexp even allows this sort of thing.

Comment: And, to make that clear: It is perfect standard syntax.
See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html (as one example of many)

Comment: Interesting you put it at the end.  I put it at the beginning because I can imagine cases where having it at the end could be ambiguous (literal - and end of class or a run a characters ending with ]?), which isn't possible at the beginning of the class.

Comment: It cannot be a sequence of characters ending in ']'. This would produce ambiguous syntax, so it is not allowed. The only place a closing square bracket may exist is right after the opening one ('[]a-z-]') or right after the negation ('[^]a-z-]').

Answer (score 7):

Escape the minus sign

```
[a-z\\-]
```

Answer (score 6):

Inside a character class `[...]` a `-` is treated specially(as a range operator) **if** it's surrounded by characters on both sides. That means if you include the `-` at the beginning or at the end of the character class it will be treated literally(non-special).

So you can use the regex:

```
^[a-z-]+$
```

or

```
^[-a-z]+$
```

Since the `-` that we added is being treated literally there is no need to escape it. Although it's not an error if you do it.

Another (less recommended) way is to not include the `-` in the character class:

```
^(?:[a-z]|-)+$
```

Note that the parenthesis are not optional in this case as `|` has a very low precedence, so with the parenthesis:

```
^[a-z]|-+$
```

Will match a lowercase alphabet at the beginning of the string and one or more `-` at the end.

Answer (score 4):

I'd rephrase the "don't put it between characters" a little more concretely.

Make the dash the first or last character in the character class.  For example "[-a-z1-9]" matches lower-case characters, digits or dash.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-z\\-]+$");
   String line = "abc-def";
   Matcher matcher = p.matcher(line);
   System.out.println(matcher.matches());  // true
```

Comment: Just curious, does it also work if your line is "abc\def"?  It seems to me that you're matching both \ and - chars.

Comment: @Parappa: Matching \ requires \\ to be in the pattern (i.e. `"^[a-z\\\\-]+$"` in Java).