# Java replaceAll fails with dollar sign in source string

Tags: java, regex

Say I have the following code

```
String test = "$abc<>";
test = test.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9./,#-' ]", "");
```

**test** is now "$abc".

Why does it keep the dollar sign?

Comment: The dollar sign is between x23 and x27. It should have cought it. Oh, but since the class is negated, it is excluded. Which would leave #$%&'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your list of characters to preserve includes `#-'`, which is a range from Unicode U+0023 (the `#` symbol) to U+0027 (the `'` symbol), including `$` (U+0024).

If you meant `#-'` to be interpreted as a list of three characters, just escape it:

```
test = test.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9./,#\\-' ]", "");
```

or put it at the end of the list:

```
test = test.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9./,#' -]", "");
```

Answer (score 7):

Because you must put the `-` as the last character in your character class.

Try

```
test.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9./,#' -]", "");
```

It'll work :)

See also [In a java regex, how can I get a character class e.g. [a-z] to match a - minus sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154031/in-a-java-regex-how-can-i-get-a-character-class-e-g-a-z-to-match-a-minus-s)

and the Javadoc for [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (Ctrl-F "Character classes")

> Note that a different set of metacharacters are in effect inside a character class than outside a character class. For instance, the regular expression . loses its special meaning inside a character class, while the expression - becomes a range forming metacharacter.